# I want the answer borders to change colors when the user doesn't click an answer

Tags: javascript

I am building a quiz app to learn javascript and I am having an issue regarding the DOM. So I would like the border colors of the answers to change to 'red' when the user doesnt click an answer, and then change back to the original color when they go to the next question, but I keep having issues where only one answer will change, either the first answer, or the last answer. I would appreciate the help, I am here to learn.

```js
gsap.from('.quiz-container', {
  duration: 1.2,
  x: '-80px',
  opacity: '0',
  ease: 'power3'
})
gsap.from('.submit-btn', {
  duration: 1.2,
  x: '-80px',
  opacity: '0',
  ease: 'power3'
})




let question = document.querySelector('.question')
let answerbox = document.querySelector('.answer-container')
let quizbox = document.querySelector('.wrapper')
let answer1 = document.getElementById('a1')
let answer2 = document.getElementById('a2')
let answer3 = document.getElementById('a3')
let answer4 = document.getElementById('a4')
let answers = document.getElementsByClassName('answer')
let submitBtn = document.getElementById('submit-btn')
let currentquestion = 0
let currentscore = 0

const questionsData = [{
    question: "How old am I?",
    answers: {
      a: "18",
      b: "21",
      c: "25",
      d: "35",
    },
    correctAnswer: "b"
  },
  {
    question: "What is my favorite color?",
    answers: {
      a: "Purple",
      b: "Green",
      c: "Black",
      d: "Red",
    },
    correctAnswer: "c"
  },
  {
    question: "What is my middle name?",
    answers: {
      a: "Albert",
      b: "David",
      c: "Graham",
      d: "John",
    },
    correctAnswer: "d"
  },
]
const loadquestion = () => {


  //console.log('working!!!')
  //GETTING THE CORRECT ANSWER //
  correctAnswer = (questionsData[currentquestion].correctAnswer)
  //INPUTTING THE QUESTIONS AND ANSWERS FROM THE QUIZDATA
  question.innerText = questionsData[currentquestion].question
  answer1.innerText = questionsData[currentquestion].answers.a
  answer2.innerText = questionsData[currentquestion].answers.b
  answer3.innerText = questionsData[currentquestion].answers.c
  answer4.innerText = questionsData[currentquestion].answers.d
  //GOING TO NEXT QUESTION
  currentquestion++

  // THIS IS THE ISSUE BELOW



  //RESETTING THE BORDERS OF THE ANSWERS IF THE USER DIDNT ANSWER THE QUESTION PREVIOUSLY
  incremented = true
  console.log(incremented)


  answer1.style.border = '2px solid rgb(59, 0, 223)'
  answer2.style.border = '2px solid rgb(59, 0, 223)'
  answer3.style.border = '2px solid rgb(59, 0, 223)'
  answer4.style.border = '2px solid rgb(59, 0, 223)'


  //RESET CLICK WHEN CLICKED OUTSIDE
  const clickreset = (e) => {
    for (i = 0; i < answers.length; i++) {
      let answerels = answers[i];
      //RESETTING THE SELECTED ANSWER WHEN THE USER MOVES ON TO THE NEXT QUESTION


      if (e.target !== answerels) {
        answerels.checked = false
      } else {
        console.log('user did not click in box')
        //RESETTING THE BORDER COLORS AFTER EACH QUESTION

        console.log(currentquestion)
      }
    }
  }
  window.addEventListener('click', clickreset)
}

loadquestion()

const endofquiz = () => {
  //GIVING RESULTS AT THE END
  question.innerText = `You answered ${currentscore} out of ${questionsData.length}`
  answer1.style.opacity = '0'
  answer2.style.opacity = '0'
  answer3.style.opacity = '0'
  answer4.style.opacity = '0'
  submitBtn.innerText = 'Restart Quiz'
  submitBtn.addEventListener('click', () => {
    //PREVENT THE SCORE FROM GOING UP AT THE END
    currentscore = currentscore
    location.reload()
  })
}

submitBtn.addEventListener('click', () => {

  //KEEP TRACK OF QUESTIONS UNTIL QUIZ IS FINISHED
  if (currentquestion <= questionsData.length) {
    for (i = 0; i < answers.length; i++) {
      let answerels = answers[i];

      //CHECK TO SEE IF USER HAS SELECTED AN ANSWER
      if (answerels.checked == true) {
        incremented == true
        //CHECK TO SEE IF USER HAS SELECTED AN ANSWER
        console.log(answerels.value)
        if (answerels.value == correctAnswer) {
          console.log("That's correct!");
          currentscore++;

        } else {
          console.log(`Sorry, the correct answer is ${questionsData[currentquestion-1].answers[correctAnswer]}.`);
        }
        if (currentquestion < questionsData.length) {
          loadquestion();
        } else {
          endofquiz();
        }
      } else {


        //STOP USER FROM GOING TO NEXT QUESTION WITHOUT SELECTING AN ANSWER
        //LETTING THE USER KNOW THEY DIDNT ANSWER THE QUESETION
        console.log(incremented)

        // THIS IS THE ISSUE BELOW

        if (incremented == false) {
          answer1.style.border = '2px solid red';
          answer2.style.border = '2px solid red';
          answer3.style.border = '2px solid red';
          answer4.style.border = '2px solid red';
        }

      }
    }
  }
})
```

```css
@import url('https://fonts.googleapis.com/css2?family=Poppins:ital,wght@0,500;0,700;1,400&family=Roboto:ital,wght@0,700;1,400&display=swap');
* {
  padding: 0;
  margin: 0;
  box-sizing: border-box;
  font-family: 'poppins', sans-serif;
}

 ::-webkit-scrollbar {
  display: none;
}

.wrapper {
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: column;
  align-items: center;
  justify-content: space-around;
}

.title {
  color: white;
  font-weight: bold;
  font-size: 2.5rem;
  text-align: center;
  color: black;
}

.quiz-container {
  margin-top: 3em;
  height: 75vh;
  width: 50vw;
  display: flex;
  border-radius: 10px;
  flex-direction: column;
  align-items: center;
  justify-content: space-evenly;
  box-shadow: rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.24) 0px 3px 8px;
}

.question-container {
  height: 20vh;
  width: 80vh;
  margin-bottom: -2em;
  /* position: absolute; */
  /* top: 10%;
        left: 50%; */
  /* transform: translate(-50%, -10%); */
  background-color: rgb(59, 0, 223);
  box-shadow: rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.24) 0px 3px 8px;
}

.question {
  padding: 1em 1.5em;
  font-size: 1.8rem;
  transition: 0.45s ease;
  text-align: center;
  color: white;
}

.answer-container {
  height: 25vh;
  width: 50vh;
  display: flex;
  margin-bottom: 8em;
  flex-direction: column;
}

label {
  background-color: white;
  padding: 0.5em;
  margin: 0.5em;
  position: relative;
  text-align: center;
  font-weight: bold;
  font-size: 1.2rem;
  cursor: pointer;
  border: 2px solid rgb(59, 0, 223);
  transition: 0.45s ease;
}

label:hover {
  background-color: rgb(59, 0, 223);
  color: white;
  cursor: pointer;
  transition: 0.45s ease;
}

input[type="radio"] {
  opacity: 0;
}


/* .answer:hover{
        background-color: rgb(59, 0, 223);
        color: white;
        cursor: pointer;
        transition: 0.45s ease;
    } */

input:checked+label {
  background-color: rgb(59, 0, 223);
  color: white;
  cursor: pointer;
  transition: 0.45s ease;
}

.submit-btn {
  margin-top: 2.5em;
  background-color: white;
  outline: none;
  border: 2px solid rgb(59, 0, 223);
  border-radius: 10px;
  padding: 0.5em 1.5em;
  font-weight: bold;
  font-size: 1.3rem;
  width: 10%;
}

.submit-btn:hover {
  color: white;
  background-color: rgb(59, 0, 223);
  transition: 0.45s ease;
  cursor: pointer;
}


/* MEDIA QUERIES FOR MOBILE PHONES */

@media only screen and (max-width: 600px) {
  .title {
    color: white;
    font-weight: bold;
    font-size: 2.5rem;
    text-align: center;
    color: black;
    margin-bottom: 0em;
  }
  .quiz-container {
    margin-top: 2em;
    width: 80vw;
    height: 68vh;
  }
  .question-container {
    width: 90%;
    height: 28%;
    margin-bottom: 2em;
  }
  .question {
    font-size: 1.6rem;
  }
  .answer-container {
    height: 30vh;
    width: 50vh;
    display: flex;
    margin-bottom: 5em;
    flex-direction: column;
  }
  label {
    background-color: white;
    padding: 0.5em;
    margin-left: 30%;
    height: 20%;
    width: 40%;
    position: relative;
    text-align: center;
    font-weight: bold;
    font-size: 0.9rem;
    cursor: pointer;
    border: 2px solid rgb(59, 0, 223);
  }
  label:hover {
    background-color: rgb(59, 0, 223);
    color: white;
    cursor: pointer;
    transition: 0.45s ease;
  }
  .submit-btn {
    background-color: white;
    outline: none;
    text-align: center;
    border: 2px solid rgb(59, 0, 223);
    padding: 1em 2em;
    font-weight: bold;
    font-size: 1rem;
    width: 65%;
  }
}
```

```html
<div class="wrapper">
  <div class="quiz-container" id="quiz-container">
    <h1 class="title">QUIZ APP</h1>
    <div class="question-container">

      <h1 class="question">Lorem ipsum, dolor sit amet consectetur adipisicing elit. Eveniet, inventore.</h1>
    </div>
    <div class="answer-container">
      <!-- <input class="answer" id='an1' type="radio" name="a"></input> <label id="a1" for="an1">lorem</label>
            <input class="answer" id='an2' type="radio" name="a"></input> <label id="a2" for="an2">lorem</label>
            <input class="answer" id='an3' type="radio" name="a"></input> <label id="a3" for="an3">lorem</label>
            <input class="answer" id='an4' type="radio" name="a"></input> <label id="a4" for="an4">lorem</label> -->
      <input class="answer" id='an1' type="radio" name="aa" value="a"></input> <label id="a1" for="an1">lorem</label>
      <input class="answer" id='an2' type="radio" name="aa" value="b"></input> <label id="a2" for="an2">lorem</label>
      <input class="answer" id='an3' type="radio" name="aa" value="c"></input> <label id="a3" for="an3">lorem</label>
      <input class="answer" id='an4' type="radio" name="aa" value="d"></input> <label id="a4" for="an4">lorem</label>
    </div>
  </div>

  <button class="submit-btn" id="submit-btn">Next Question</button>
</div>



<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/gsap/3.6.1/gsap.min.js" integrity="sha512-cdV6j5t5o24hkSciVrb8Ki6FveC2SgwGfLE31+ZQRHAeSRxYhAQskLkq3dLm8ZcWe1N3vBOEYmmbhzf7NTtFFQ==" crossorigin="anonymous" referrerpolicy="no-referrer"></script>
```

Comment: `incremented = true` where is it set to false?